# Can't read first string

Tags: c++, string, cin

Here is the code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#define limit 25
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int te; //Number of test cases
    cin>>te;


    while(te)
    {

    char m[limit];
    char w[limit];

    cin.getline(m,limit); // This line is not getting executed for some reason
    cin.getline(w,limit);

    cout<<"m "<<m<<" "<<endl<<"w "<<w<<endl;

    te--;

    }

}
```

For god knows what reason, the machine refuses to read m for the first test case. It reads and prints values for both m and w in the other cases, but for the first case, it refuses to read m.

Sample:

```
INPUT
1
hello


m is 
w is hello


2

hello
m 
w  hello

stack
overflow

m  stack
w overflow
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cin>>te;
```

This will extract the `1` from the input stream and then stop at but not extract the `\n`. You'll need to `ignore()` that character, otherwise the next line extraction you do will just read an empty line.

```
cin.ignore();
```

Or to ignore *all* characters up to and including the next `\n` character (in case somebody inputs `1foo` or something), you can do:

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It solved my problem. The question I wanted to ask is if cin causes a left over character in the stream, then why does it not happen to me all the time. Why did it occur on only this particular instance?

Comment: @Piyush It's not `cin` itself. It's the way you use `cin`. When you use `>>` to extract data, its typically known as *formatted input function*. It first extracts and discards whitespace and then reads out the appropriate formatted text (numbers for `int`, a word for `std::string`) and then stops. If you use `>>` once, yes, the newline will be left. If you then use it again, the newline will be discarded at the beginning. The problem arises when you mix formatted input with *unformatted input functions*. These do *not*, by default, extract whitespace at the beginning. `getline` is an example.

Comment: @Piyush No problem. The I/O library is admittedly quite confusing.

Comment: @Piyush Because most teachers (as with most C++ programmers) don't understand it fully. They know that they can use `>>` to extract a specific type and `getline` to extract a line, but they often don't understand the specifics of what is happening.